# How to change property of item in ImmutableList({}) inside Immutable.Map({})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, immutable.js

How do I change property of item in `ImmutableList({})` that is inside `Immutable.Map({})`?

I have:

```
const initialState = Immutable.Map({
    width: window.board.width,
    height: window.board.height,
    lines: Immutable.List([
        Immutable.Map({id: 1, active: false, name: 'Some name'}),
        Immutable.Map({id: 2, active: false, name: 'Sad name'}),
        Immutable.Map({id: 3, active: true, name: 'Cool name'})
    ])
});
```

Lets say I want to set item with `id` 1 in the List. Then change its property active to true. I also want to set property active to false for all the other items in the List.

How do I do that? Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit (final solution):**

```
export function activateLine(lineId) {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        const updatedLines = getState().board.update('lines', Immutable.List(),
            (oldList) => oldList.map((listItem) => {
                return listItem.set("active", (listItem.get("id") === lineId));
            })).get('lines');

        return dispatch({
            type: types.ACTIVATE_LINE,
            payload: updatedLines
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by change an immutable? the point is that you can't; you must duplicate and merge...

Comment: I want to return new Immutable map with new values.

Comment: How do I duplicate it and merge it? Could you please show me an example? That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't know I am kind of new to javascript. I though it is a good ideat o have immutable state in redux. It is a lot of pain though because I am not really familiar with immutable API which is extremely confusing for people who are not experience in procedural programming.

Comment: Yeah, just wrap this whole object in `immutable.fromJS({...your object})`, then the entire thing will be immutable and you dont have to sub divide each section.

Comment: When I do `Immutable.toJS(initialState)` I get `_immutable2.default.toJS is not a function`. How can this be so complicated?? It is just two dimension structure.

Comment: `Immutable.fromJS(initialState)` . Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse immutable like so (quick note though i would highly recommend you make the entire object immutable). You can keep down the lines of code and keep it a bit more elegant by **just** using immutable itself -

```
const changeImmutableObject = initialState.update('lines', Immutable.List(),
    (oldList) => oldList.map((listItem) => {
        if(listItem.get("id") === 1) {
            return listItem.set("active", true);
        } else {
            return listItem.set("active", false);
        }
    })
  )
```

See working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o04btr3j/214/

This updates the `list` key inside your object (if it is not there for whatever reason it defaults to an immutable list), then maps over the properties. If it has an id of 1, it will set active to true, otherwise it will set active to false.

You can also just `initialState.toJS()` your immutable object and do your logic in plain js, or do and `immutableobject.get('property')` and modify and then set that back in your object, however I would recommend you just use the built in methods in immutable as it is *much less code*.

Also, If I'm not mistaken you can just do something like this :

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
width: window.board.width,
height: window.board.height,
lines:[
    {id: 1, active: false, name: 'Some name'},
    {id: 2, active: false, name: 'Sad name'},
    {id: 3, active: true, name: 'Cool name'}
]
});
```

You can immutable.fromJS() an object to put it into an immutable object. And all immutable objects should have a .toJS method on them to turn them back into regular javascript objects/lists/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I have created lithe example on [link to solution on jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/piyakiyoga/edit?js,console)

```
const initialState = Immutable.Map({
    lines: Immutable.List([
        Immutable.Map({id: 1, active: false, name: 'Some name'}),
        Immutable.Map({id: 2, active: false, name: 'Sad name'}),
        Immutable.Map({id: 3, active: true, name: 'Cool name'})
    ])
});


console.log('initialState', initialState.toJS())

// update lines, map over items and set active to false
const stateLinesAllNotActive = initialState.updateIn(
  ['lines'], 
  items => items.map((item) => item.set('active', false)) 
)

console.log('stateLinesAllNotActive', stateLinesAllNotActive.toJS())

// lines and key for item with id === 1, then set active to this item
const stateFirstActive = stateLinesAllNotActive.updateIn(
  [
    'lines', 
    stateLinesAllNotActive.get('lines').findIndex((item) => (item.get("id") === 1))
  ],
  item => item.set("active", true)
)

console.log('stateFirstActive', stateFirstActive.toJS())
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just accepted ajmajmajma's answer though.

Answer (score 0):

What follows should work, but, as someone said... I think could be better a full update...

```js
const initialState = Immutable.Map({
    lines: Immutable.List([
        Immutable.Map({id: 1, active: false, name: 'Some name'}),
        Immutable.Map({id: 2, active: false, name: 'Sad name'}),
        Immutable.Map({id: 3, active: true, name: 'Cool name'})
    ])
});

let lines = initialState.get('lines'); 
let id = 1; // what you want update...
let updater = item => {
  let updated = item.set('name', "Giuseppe");
  
  return updated;
};
let index = lines.findIndex((i) => i.get("id") === id);
let result = lines.update(index, updater);

initialState.set("lines", result);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: That looks great. I get an error though: `Uncaught TypeError: k is not a function`

Comment: but someone love downvoting... it could be accepted?

Comment: Not downvoter here - but you are pulling a sub section out of immutable when it does not need to be, and also not meeting the business logic OP is requesting (change active to true and false etc..)

Comment: Yeah friend, no problem... Just a note, you should comment after downvoting and not only when requested: That's costructive. I updated the `name` props that's almost the same... The important thing is the logic. For the `pull out a subsection`, that's true... you're probably right, it was no needed.

Comment: Thank you both. I like Hitmands's solution too because now I also can find index of a given item and update it. Immutable API is really confusing. I decided to use ajmajmajma's solution though. It is much simpler.